How can i save drawing file correctly in Autocad?
I use .NET framework and C# language to customize Autocad software.
I have problem with save drawing file.
Autocad 2024
In Autocad developing i have problem with saving active drawing file.
I'm trying to use the following code to save file.
But, i give exception error like:
"Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime.Exception: 'eFileAccessErr'" Or, "internal error: !dbobji!.cpp@8668: eNotOpenForWrite"
`
// (C) Copyright 2024 by
//
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.EditorInput;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Geometry;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime;
using System;
// This line is not mandatory, but improves loading performances
[assembly: CommandClass(typeof(Strore_lab01.MyCommands))]

namespace Strore_lab01
{
// This class is instantiated by AutoCAD for each document when
// a command is called by the user the first time in the context
// of a given document. In other words, non static data in this class
// is implicitly per-document!
public class MyCommands
{
    [CommandMethod("SaveActiveDrawing")]
    public static void SaveActiveDrawing()
    {
        Document acDoc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
        string strDWGName = acDoc.Name;

        object obj = Application.GetSystemVariable("DWGTITLED");

        // Check to see if the drawing has been named
        if (System.Convert.ToInt16(obj) == 0)
        {
            // If the drawing is using a default name (Drawing1, Drawing2, etc)
            // then provide a new name
            strDWGName = "c:\\MyDrawing.dwg";
        }

        // Save the active drawing
        acDoc.Database.SaveAs(strDWGName, true, DwgVersion.Current, acDoc.Database.SecurityParameters);
        
        }

    }

}

`

Non-elevated users are typically not allowed to write to the root directory.
